# GetConnect Post API calls not working in Flutter Web says : 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using GetConnect for API call in my Flutter project.

getx version : 4.6.6
Flutter version : 3.16

Here is the API call function:

```
class ApiProvider extends GetConnect {

    @override
    void onInit() {
        httpClient.baseUrl = BASE_URL;
        httpClient.defaultContentType = "application/json";
        httpClient.maxAuthRetries = 3;
        httpClient.timeout = Duration(seconds: 600);
    }

    Future<Response> loginUserApi(LoginRequest data) =>
      post("v1/user/signIn", json.encode(data.toJson()),
          contentType: "application/json" , headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'App-ID': 'CUSTOMER',
          } );
        }
```

This function is working fine on Android and iOS devices, but when I run my project on Flutter Web, it says:

> [GETX] Cannot decode server response to json

And in network tab of Chrome it says:

> Status Code : 415 Unsupported Media Type

When I call same API using dio it's working on Flutter Web and other platforms.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting Flutter web in Chrome, I noticed that when I set 'Content-Type': 'application/json', it results in the Content-Type being set twice. This  I noticed in inspect window's network tab, where the Content-Type shows as "application/json application/json" within the request headers, refer to screenshot below:

[image]

This issue led to the server responding with a **415 Unsupported Media Type** error. It appears that on Flutter web, `httpClient.defaultContentType = "application/json";` works, so there is no need to set content type again. However, on mobile, we must explicitly set the content type within our headers. As a solution, I modified my provider as follows:

```dart
class BffApiProvider extends GetConnect {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    httpClient.baseUrl = BFF_BASE_URL;
    httpClient.defaultContentType = "application/json";
    httpClient.maxAuthRetries = 3;
    httpClient.timeout = Duration(seconds: 600);

    var headers;
    if (kIsWeb) {
      headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      };
    } else {
      headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      };
    }

    // for login
    Future<Response> loginUserApi(LoginRequest data) =>
        post("user/signIn", json.encode(data.toJson()));
  }
}
```

Now, all POST API calls work correctly on both mobile and Flutter web. I hope this solution helps someone using GetConnect for API calls in Flutter. Happy coding!